# login using stored procedure not working in html5

Tags: sql, asp.net, html, stored-procedures

Following is the code I write for the login, I want when I type in the userName and Password, it can confirm with the database and make sure is correct then go to the home.aspx.

My stored procedure is:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `login`(in userName varchar(50), in password varchar(50))
BEGIN
select * from `users`
where `users`.`userName`=UserName
and `users`.`password`=Password;
END
```

and my database is MySQL, I don't know where is wrong, the system does not match the database userName and Password. The screen shot of users table order:

[image: User table]

```
    protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string UserName = txtUserName.ToString();
        string Password = txtPassword.ToString();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstr);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("login", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserName",Server.HtmlEncode(txtUserName.Value));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Password", Server.HtmlEncode(txtPassword.Value));

        SqlDataReader rdr;
        conn.Open();
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        rdr.Read();
        if (rdr.HasRows)
        {
            Session["UserName"] = rdr.GetString(1);
            Session["Password"] = rdr.GetString(2);
            Page.Response.Redirect("home.aspx");

        }
        else
        {
            lblMsg.Text = "Please check your user name or password";
        }
        rdr.Close();
        cmd.Dispose();
        conn.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: Nah, doesn't work, it just a injection, not really matter. as I tried, the if sentence did not execute, the lblMsg box didn't even show the error message

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do `Server.HtmlEncode` when you lookup the name/password in the database. 

You should really separate the data and it's presentation. 
HTML-Encoding does not belong in text stored in a database.
If you need to store an international name, set the field's encoding to UTF8.
Also, please don't use sessions, especially not for user management. 
You will not be able to be logged in with 2 users at the same time (if you store page data in session, not even two tabs for the same user), and the session will expire in 20 minutes, and then you get NULL-reference exceptions everywhere. 
I currently have to maintain (=rewrite a part whenever I have the chance) such a system. 
It's a nightmare. Plus there's already forms-authentication cookies for that, which does the job much better. 

Also, you should use a using-clause around your connection and command.
If you don't, the connection won't be closed on every exception, and your connection pool will sooner or later exceed its maximum capacity ==> error

Also, before you do conn.Open(), you should check that the connection is not already open (same for close).

And please please do NOT use indices in the GetString or GetValue methods of datareader. Always use the field's name.

```
dr.GetValue(dr.GetOrdinal("COLUMN_Name"));
```

If someone adds a field not at the end, that WILL BREAK your code.
Do not micro-optimize performance in this way when it is absolutely not necessary (using indices pretty much never is).

And the correct way to read is

```
if (dReader.HasRows) 
{
    while (dReader.Read()) 
    {
        // GetValue comes here
    }
}
```

You might also want to add a LIMIT 1 to your sql-statement, just in case you didn't put a unique index on username.

Something you can build on perhaps:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;


namespace SimpleLoginSite
{


    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {


        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        } // End Sub Page_Load 


        protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connstr = GetConnectionString();


            using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connstr))
            {
                string UserName = txtUserName.ToString();
                string Password = txtPassword.ToString();

                using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("login", conn))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserName", Server.HtmlEncode(this.txtUserName.Text));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Password", Server.HtmlEncode(this.txtPassword.Text));

                    if (conn.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                        conn.Open();

                    using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
                    {

                        if (rdr.HasRows)
                        {
                            while (rdr.Read())
                            {
                                Session["UserName"] = rdr.GetString(rdr.GetOrdinal("username"));
                                Session["Password"] = rdr.GetString(rdr.GetOrdinal("password"));

                                Page.Response.Redirect("home.aspx");
                            } // Whend 
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            lblMsg.Text = "Please check your user name or password";
                            lblMsg.Visible = true;
                        }


                        if (!rdr.IsClosed)
                            rdr.Close();

                    } // End Using SqlDataReader rdr

                } // End Using SqlCommand cmd

                if (conn.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                    conn.Close();
            } // End Using SqlConnection conn 

        } // End Sub btnLogin_Click 


        public static string GetConnectionString()
        {
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder csb = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            csb.DataSource = "localhost";
            csb.InitialCatalog = "TestDB";

            csb.IntegratedSecurity = true;

            if (!csb.IntegratedSecurity)
            {
                csb.UserID = "ApertureWebServicesDE";
                csb.Password = "TopSecret";
            }

            return csb.ConnectionString;
        } // End Function  GetConnectionString


    } // End partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page


} // End Namespace SimpleLoginSite
```

And the aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="SimpleLoginSite.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>

    <style type="text/css" media="all">


    label 
    {
        display:block;
        float: left;
        width: 100px;
        text-align: right;
        padding-right: 0.25cm;
    }

    input
    {
        width: 300px;
    }

    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Login</legend>
            <label for="txtUserName">Username:</label>
            <asp:TextBox name="name" ID="txtUserName" placeholder="e.g. john.doe@example.com" runat="server" />
            <br />
            <label for="txtPassword">Password:</label>
            <asp:TextBox name="txtPassword" ID="txtPassword" placeholder="e.g. Open Sesame" TextMode="Password" runat="server" />
            <br /><br />
            <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" Text="Login"  runat="server" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" />
        </fieldset>
    </div>
        <asp:Label ID="lblMsg" Text="" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the stored precedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[login]
      @userName varchar(50) 
     ,@password varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET @userName = 'MyUser';
    -- SET @password = 'MyPassword';

    SELECT * 
    FROM users

    WHERE users.username = @userName 
    AND users.password = @password 
    ;

END

GO
```

**PS:** 
It looks like your stored procedure is MySQL, but you're using System.Data.SqlClient.
You need to use MySql.Data.MySqlClient instead if you use MySQL.
Also, you shouldn't redirect within the SQL statement.
Get the user first, then redirect.

Comment: so, what should I do?

Comment: @Eric Val: How about adding the while statement, adding the using clauses and GetOrdinal to your code, and remove htmlencode and session ? Learn to use Google perhaps.